# Proper way to query table for RLS

Tags: sql, supabase, row-level-security

I'm sure this is a common question but I cannot find the answer. I want to query a separate table called `users` and check if they have property `is_moderator` = `true`.

```
(EXISTS ( SELECT 1
   FROM users
  WHERE ((users.user_id = auth.uid()) AND (users.is_moderator = true))))
```

[image: Heres what I have so far]

I tried to delete `users.user_id = auth.uid()` just to check if any users have `is_moderator` and it still does not work.
It's as if it isn't even querying the `users` table .
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You don't need `= true` as it's already a `boolean`, you just need `AND users.is_moderator)`

Comment: Does the user accessing this table have access to the `users` table? If not, you might want to use security definer functions. https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/row-level-security#using-security-definer-functions